# Problemas con autoScroll en C# y Windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Windows Forms en C# y me he quebrado la cabeza intentando resolver el problema con el autoScroll.

Tengo un formulario y dentro de el tengo dos paneles, el primero con dock a la izquierda y el otro con dockStyle.Fill

El problema es que dentro de este último panel abro un formulario

```
private void AbrirFormulario(Form form)
    {
        if (formularioactivo != null)
            formularioactivo.Close();
        formularioactivo = form;
        form.TopLevel = false;
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelcontenedor.Controls.Add(form);
        panelcontenedor.Tag = form;
        form.BringToFront();
        form.Show();
    }
```

Este formulario necesita un scrollBar vertical y cuando lo activo desde el formulario que voy a abrir se desborda, es decir, no puedo bajar completamente.

Comment: Que quieres decir con abres un formulario dentro de un panel, no entiendo eso

Comment: @Japv alli esta el método